# SAPUI5 code reuse: fragments vs. controls vs. views

Tags: architecture, sapui5

When should be fragments vs. controls vs. views chosen to achieve the best results and earn the full benefits? The concepts seem very similar, some have strength and weaknesses (development overhead or runtime overhead). I am looking for the most practical design approach.

I am thinking especially of reusing custom popups, tables and header views. Asking this question in the context to reuse these components within one project and across similar project, for example to integrate in a custom library.

Answer (score 0):

For popup contents, fragments are most reasonable for reuse.

If you want to reuse code and markup between project, I think it is better to wrap it into a custom composite control, so you will have a clear API. However, there are no strict rules when to use one of the mentioned reuse possibilities.